# How to stretch a vbox to fit it's parent PlainTeX?

Tags: graphics, plain-tex

I'm trying to create a white square that has 1pt wide black border. This is my code so far:

```
\def\blankbox#1{
    \hbox to #1{
        \vrule
        \vbox to #1 {
            \hrule
            \vfil
            \hrule 
        }   
        \vrule
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please remove the “accept” mark from my answer, so that I csn delete it: @egreg has now corrected the slight oversight in his answer, which is now what I would call *the* answer to your question!

Comment: Sorry, it took me so long ... Marked the correct answer.
cc @GuM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protect the end of lines and assign a width to the `\hrule`

```
\def\blankbox#1{%
    \hbox to #1{%
        \vrule\hss
        \vbox to #1 {
            \hrule width #1
            \vfil
            \hrule
        }%
        \hss\vrule
    }%
}

\blankbox{1cm}

\bye
```

If you want to vary the thickness:

```
\def\blankbox#1#2{%
    \hbox to #2{%
        \vrule width #1 \hss
        \vbox to #2 {
            \hrule width #2 height #1
            \vfil
            \hrule height #1
        }%
        \hss \vrule width #1
    }%
}

\noindent
\blankbox{0.4pt}{1cm}\qquad\blankbox{2pt}{1cm}

\bye
```

This gives a box where the area is bounded internally by the rules. A more generic approach allows to have different placements of the rule: `\iblankbox` as before, `\mblankbox` for “mid way” placement, `\oblankbox` for “outer”.

```
\def\gblankbox#1#2#3{%
  \dimen0=#2\relax
  \dimen2=#3\relax
  \advance\dimen2 by #1\dimen0
  \hbox to \dimen2{%
    \vrule width \dimen0\hss
    \vbox to \dimen2 {
      \hrule width \dimen2 height \dimen0
      \vfil
      \hrule height \dimen0
    }%
      \hss \vrule width \dimen0
  }%
}
\def\iblankbox{\gblankbox{0}}
\def\mblankbox{\gblankbox{1}}
\def\oblankbox{\gblankbox{2}}

\noindent
\iblankbox{0.4pt}{1cm}\qquad\iblankbox{2pt}{1cm}

\noindent
\mblankbox{0.4pt}{1cm}\qquad\mblankbox{2pt}{1cm}

\noindent
\oblankbox{0.4pt}{1cm}\qquad\oblankbox{2pt}{1cm}

\noindent
\setbox0=\hbox{\iblankbox{1pt}{10pt}}
width = \the\wd0; height = \the\ht0

\noindent
\setbox0=\hbox{\mblankbox{1pt}{10pt}}
width = \the\wd0; height = \the\ht0

\noindent
\setbox0=\hbox{\oblankbox{1pt}{10pt}}
width = \the\wd0; height = \the\ht0

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This works as expected:

```
\def\blankbox#1{% <-- important!
    \hbox{% <-- important!
        \vrule width 5pt
        \kern -5pt
        \vbox to #1 {%
            \hrule height 5pt width #1
            \vfil
            \hrule height 5pt
        }% <-- important!
        \kern -5pt
        \vrule width 5pt
    }% <-- important!
}

\noindent\blankbox{3cm}

\showboxbreadth = 100
\showboxdepth = 10
\tracingonline = 1
\showlists

\dimen0 = 3cm
\showthe\dimen0

\bye
```

The diagnostic commands help you verify that the box actually has the dimensions you want.  Note that one has to “comment out” every “end of line” that occurs in horizontal mode (at least).  Of course, after checking that the box is square, replace `5pt` with `1pt` throughout the code.